# Deploying Trail and Full version settings using Adobe Air for iOS/Android

Tags: ios, flash, air, app-store, demo

How to deploy demo/trial version from iOS/Android Apps using Adobe Flash/Adobe Air to upload my app to the appstore or android market.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple actively rejects anything beta.  I'd assume they'd reject anything trial that expires.

Per demo vs "full" versions, I'd assume you would release:

- **Demo** - Release a scaled back free version of your app
- **Full** - Release a full featured paid app at some pricing tier

This would be no different than [Angry Birds Free Edition](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds-free/id409807569?mt=8) and other versions such as [Angry Birds Space for $0.99](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/angry-birds-space/id499511971?mt=8).

Android Market / Google Play has fewer restrictions.

Comment: Do you have a link to show me how to create demo and full for the same app id?

Comment: They would be two discrete apps - each having a different app id and bundle.